# How do I define the size and location of a pop up sub VI when calling it in my main program?

Tags: loops, resize, location, subroutine, labview

I have a main program which calls several sub VIs.  Each sub VI has either a button, or timer or something which the operator must view or interact with while still monitoring the main front panel.  How do I define the size and location of each sub VI as it pops up when called?

In the image below I have my main front panel with my gauges, etc and I have the sub VI in the location and of the size I require.  How do I ensure that each time the sub VI is called it pops up here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that in the sub VI you can control the properties by going to Tools -> Properties and then changing the tab to select window size and appearance.

Answer (score 0):

What about moving such controls into the Main VI Front Panel ? It may look better in overall than pop up windows just to launch the application.

Also you can use tabs if there is lack of space on your Front Panel.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using subpanels. You can use them to display the panels of subVIs at specific positions in the main VI. You can use Static VI references to reference the specific subVIs.

If for some reason you don't want this, you can also control the position dynamically, not just statically. You will need to use property nodes for that and set the VI's FP window bounds property.

Comment: I don't have any room on my main VI front panel for the 9 different VIs that I'm calling (corresponding to 9 different types of tests I'm running).  I also want my sub VI to close after it's completed its task.  Will I be able to call the sub VI, view it using a sub panel and then close it when it's finished?

Comment: A subpanel is completely separate from the VIs - you can insert and remove VIs as you like, whether they're running or not. It's certainly possible to reuse the same the subpanel for multiple VIs, and you can see an example in the LV options dialog, where the list on the left selects which VI to display on the right. Look at the examples and play with it.